# Primefaces lazy datatable does not recognize method load

Tags: primefaces

I have a primefaces datatable below:

```
<p:dataTable id="table_lista_grupos" value="#{grupoClasseBean.gldm}" var="item" 
   widgetVar="lista_grupos" rowKey="#{item.codigo}" paginator="true" rows="10" 
   styleClass="panelGrande" paginatorPosition="bottom" sortMode="multiple" 
   filteredValue="#{grupoClasseBean.listaGruposFiltrados}" rowHover="true" 
   resizeMode="expand" selectionMode="single" lazy="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30"
   paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" >
```

and I need implementing a lazy load,
I followed the documentation and I created the class below:

```
public class GrupoLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Grupo>{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private List<Grupo> datasource;
    
    public GrupoLazyDataModel(List<Grupo> datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
        setRowCount(datasource.size());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Grupo> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        return new ArrayList<Grupo>();
    }
}
```

and I call this class in my ManagedBean

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class GrupoClasseBean implements Serializable {
    
    private LazyDataModel<Grupo> gldm;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Map<TipoParametro, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(TipoParametro.TIPO, tipo);
        listaGrupos = (List<Grupo>) rule.list(0, 100, params);
        gldm = new GrupoLazyDataModel(listaGrupos);        
    }
}
```

but when I execute my software, I receive the error message:

```
 Receiver class br.gov.sp.sefaz.siafem.cm.ui.grpcls.GrupoLazyDataModel does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract load(IILjava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/List; of abstract class org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.
```

My environment is primefaces 5.3, tomcat 9, jdk 1.8, netbeans 12.2, database derby

Comment: Are you sure your code is compiled and deployed without errors? Do you compile your project with the same jdk you're running it?

Comment: Your bean must at least be `@ViewScoped` in order for lazy to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue updating the primefaces version, from 5.3 to 10.0